# Update metadata while uploading chunk of object in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

UseCase: I am doing a multipart upload to S3 and while uploading first part I get to know the content-type. Trying to update the metadata for the part doesn;t work in updating the contentType of the object at s3.

Is the only time you can allow object level metadata at the time of establishing the Multipart connection?

Comment: Not sure this needs the scala tag. Maybe edit your question if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the only time you can set the metadata on an S3 multipart upload is when you initiate the upload.

Not knowing the specific circumstances, it sounds as if you should be able to simply wait to initiate the upload until you have enough information to determine the content-type.

Comment: yeah, thats what I figured out. 
Don't like the workaround of copying the object again to do set the content-type.

Comment: sorry but I try to find documentation of aws about this:
`Correct, the only time you can set the metadata on an S3 multipart upload is when you initiate the upload.`

Can you guy share link? 
Many thanks!